# Проверка input на слова

Tags: javascript

Есть у меня код и массив со словами. Есть input с кнопкой. Код работает, но некорентно. Надо чтобы выскакивал alert с предупреждением, когда ввожу слова из массива. Массив я проитерував. В чем моя ошибка?

```
HTML

<input type="text" id="myText">
<button id="task5">Написать комментарий</button>

JS
let badWords = [ 'Очень плохое слово', 'Плохое слово'];
let button = document.getElementById('task5');
let inputs = document.getElementById('myText');
for (let words of badWords)
button.onclick = function checkWords () {
 if (inputs.value = words){
alert('Аяйяй, Так говорить не можно');
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let badWords = [ 'очень плохое слово', 'плохое слово']; // всё маленькими буквами
let button = document.getElementById('task5');
let inputs = document.getElementById('myText');

button.onclick = () => {
  if (badWords.includes(inputs.value.toLowerCase())) {
    alert('Аяйяй, Так говорить не можно');
  } else {
    console.log(inputs.value);
  }
};
```

Comment: Блин, я про includes забыл. Спасибо большое)

Comment: @Halland если Вам помог мой ответ, то поставьте пожалуйста галочку :)

Comment: хорошо, но где?)

Comment: @Halland напротив ответа она)) обычно как раз её тыкают если ответ каког-либо участника помог. Ну и стрелку вверх тоже

Comment: @RuslanMart, я прошу прощения, можно еще последний вопрос задать относительно кода?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский конечно

Comment: @RuslanMart вы ошиблись адресатом)

Comment: @RuslanMart Как сделать чтобы в консоль выводится все слова кроме слов из массива при введении в input?